# Invoked Webjob not considering arguments passed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm invoking a webjob from my WebApp hosted in an App Service Environment. The code I used to invoke is below:

```
string userName = "$xxxx";
                    string userPassword = "xxxxx";
                    string webJobName = "xxxx";

                    var unEncodedString = String.Format($"{ userName}:{ userPassword}");
                    var encodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(unEncodedString));
                    string URL = string.Format("https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/" + webJobName + "/run?arguments={0}", jobId.ToString());
                    System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL);
                    request.Method = "POST";
                    request.ContentLength = 0;
                    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " +encodedString;
                    response = request.GetResponse();
```

I am invoking a webjob which is a console application. How I handle the argument in the console application is as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //
            var id = 0;
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                if (!int.TryParse(args[0].ToString(), out id))
                    id = 0;   
            }


            if (id > 0)
            {
                EmailJobExecution emailServ = new EmailJobExecution();
                EmailJobDBContext jobDB = new EmailJobDBContext();

                var jobs = jobDB.getActiveJob(id);

                List<string> logs = new List<string>();
                emailServ.ExecuteJob(jobs, out logs);

                foreach (var item in logs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is I can see in the Webjob dashboard the webjob is been invoked but the arguments aren't passed. The Log displays as:

> [05/30/2017 11:18:51 > 738495: SYS INFO] Status changed to
>   Initializing
>
> [05/30/2017 11:18:51 > 738495: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with
>   script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
>
> [05/30/2017 11:18:51 > 738495: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
>
> [05/30/2017 11:18:51 > 738495: INFO]
>
> [05/30/2017 11:18:51 > 738495: INFO]
>   D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\xxxxx\rwjgkw42.ann>xxxx.EXE
>
> [05/30/2017 11:18:51 > 738495: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success

If I went to App Service Editor and amend the run.cmd like this: `xxxx.EXE 1` (1 is argument) then I the console takes argument and log like this:

> [05/30/2017 10:17:26 > 738495: SYS INFO] Status changed to
>   Initializing
>
> [05/30/2017 10:17:27 > 738495: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with
>   script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
>
> [05/30/2017 10:17:27 > 738495: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
>
> [05/30/2017 10:17:27 > 738495: INFO]
>
> [05/30/2017 10:17:27 > 738495: INFO]
>   D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\xxxx\bvck11x1.f3v>xxx.EXE
>   1
>
> [05/30/2017 10:17:32 > 738495: INFO] 5/30/2017 10:17:27 AM: Job No. 1
>   Started
>
> [05/30/2017 10:17:32 > 738495: INFO] Message Count: 1
>
> [05/30/2017 10:17:32 > 738495: INFO] 1:OK
>
> [05/30/2017 10:17:32 > 738495: INFO] Status Count: 1
>
> [05/30/2017 10:17:32 > 738495: INFO] 5/30/2017 10:17:32 AM: Job No. 1
>   Completed
>
> [05/30/2017 10:17:32 > 738495: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success

The Argument does not pass even if I run the URL in Postman.

Please help me resolve this.

> **Update 31st May 2017:**
>
> The Zip Package for Webjobs had the following:
>
> 1. run.cmd
> 2. xxxx.EXE
>
> and as @SuwatCh guided me, I removed the `run.cmd` and leaving only the
>   `*.exe` in Zip Package and then created the WebJob and finally it worked!

Comment: Did you provide your own run.cmd?  If so, you will have to make sure all arguments propagate (eg %1 or %*) any exe launched by run.cmd.

Comment: @SuwatCh Yes I had my own run.cmd and I removed the `run.cmd` leaving only the `*.exe` and it worked! Glad you gave me something to think :)

Comment: Since the issue is solved, we suggest you post your solution as a reply and mark it as answer.

Comment: @Amor-MSFT sure will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for such did not work accordingly, is that the Zip package did have my own run.cmd.

> Prior to the resolution I had in my Zip Package are:
>
> 1. run.cmd
> 2. *.dlls
> 3. xxxx.EXE

To resolve I had to remove the `run.cmd` in my Zip package and it worked! :)

Answer (score 2):

Passing argument that way should work fine. Please test with a minimal app, since everything you're doing related to EmailJobExecution has no bearing on the question and should be omitted. Also, your client code is not relevant to the question if you also repro with postman, so please leave that out.

e.g. I just tried with a trivial batch file containing just:

```
echo Hello Azure WebJob!
echo command line arg %1
echo env variable %WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS%
```

And both `%1` and `%WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS%` correctly have the passed in value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Refer updated section in my post for the resolution. Thank you again!